# ExtensionContributionFactory to add toolbar menu dynamically is not working in eclipse 4

Tags: eclipse-plugin

I have a eclipse application which contributes to "org.eclipse.ui.menus" to add toolbar menu items dynamically in org.eclipse.ui.main.toolbar. 
it was working fine with 3.8

Recently I migrated my application to eclipse 4.6. After migration toolbar menus are not visible and what I observed is class specified in extension point in not getting invoked.

Is there any other way to achieve same functionality?

following is code I am using :

```
public class ToolbarProvider extends ExtensionContributionFactory
{

public ToolbarProvider()
{
}

@Override
public void createContributionItems( IServiceLocator serviceLocator, IContributionRoot additions )
{
    ToolBarContributionItem toolbar = new ToolBarContributionItem( );
    additions.addContributionItem( toolbar, null );
    CommandContributionItemParameter p = new CommandContributionItemParameter( serviceLocator, "", "org.eclipse.ui.file.exit",
            SWT.PUSH );
    p.label = "Exit";
    p.icon = Activator.getImageDescriptor( "icons/alt_window_16.gif" );
    CommandContributionItem item = new CommandContributionItem( p );
    item.setVisible( true );

    toolbar.getToolBarManager().add( item );
}

}
```

code in plugin.xml :

```
    <extension point="org.eclipse.ui.menus">
<menuContribution
class="server.ui.ToolbarContributionFactory"
locationURI="toolbar:org.eclipse.ui.main.toolbar"
</menuContribution>
</extension>
```

Comment: Show us the code you were using.

Comment: updated the sample code. I Guess problem is not with code because same is working in eclipse 3.8

Comment: Show us how this is set up in the org.eclipse.ui.menus extension point

Comment: Probably Eclipse bug [411765](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=411765)